# Trying to dynamically update textboxes with values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have put a map into excel of a building seating chart and created activeX text boxes on each spot where someone is sitting. I also have a list of each seat and the person sitting there. What I want to do is go through the list and assign the correct name to the textbox for each person. The name of each textbox is "TextBox____" where the blank is the seat name". I am getting an error on the "set tbox" line.

```
Sub UpdateMap()
   Dim name As Variant
   Dim tbox As MSForms.TextBox
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim cell As Range
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5th floor map")
   Set rng = .Range("A2:A5")
   For Each cell In rng
    ws = cell.Value
    name = Application.VLookup(ws, .Range("A2:B5"), 2, False)
    Set tbox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5th floor map").Shapes("TextBox" & ws)
    tbox.Value = name
    Next
   End With
End Sub
```

I only used the first four names/seats for this example, and used the for loop because in reality there are over 100 of these. Any suggestions for how i could make this work would be appreciated. Or if I am thinking about this totally wrong, please tell me that too. Thanks.

Comment: "I am getting an error" What error?

Comment: Runtime error 13 - type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub UpdateMap()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5th floor map")
    Set rng = .Range("A2:A5")
    For Each cell In rng
        .OLEObjects("TextBox" & cell).Object.Text = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much. One quick additional question. If I want to also update font, fill, etc in the textboxes, what would I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub oo()
Dim ol As OLEObject

Set ol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").OLEObjects("TextBox1")
With ol
    .Object.Text = "blabla"
    .Object.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 192)
    .Object.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    .Object.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
    .Object.BackColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    '.object.....


End With

End Sub
```